# How to get value of particular selector with same id?

Tags: javascript

How to get value of particular selector with same id?

```
function rev() {
  var username = document.getElementById(value).value; /// or textContent;
  return alert (username);
}

 <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey</button>
 <button id="but" onclick="rev()">hey233</button>
```

But the reult always HEY

Any ideas?

Comment: you can't duplicate id instead of use class

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have duplicate elements with the same ids. Its just not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` attribute for the elements must be unique. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) :

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

**Work Around:**

You can use `class` or custom `data-*` attributes to get along with your logic. Read more about `data-*` attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need seperate these, with the buttons having different ids

```
function rev1() {
  var username = document.getElementById("but1").value; /// or textContent;
  return alert (username);
}

function rev2() {
  var username = document.getElementById("but2").value; /// or textContent;
  return alert (username);
}
 <button id="but1" onclick="rev1()">hey</button>
 <button id="but2" onclick="rev2()">hey233</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [Element `id` must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). But for what you are doing you do not need an `id` to get the text content of the button upon 'click', as the handler `event` knows the `target` element that was clicked.

```js
function handler(event) {
  alert(event.target.textContent);
}

var forEach = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
forEach(buttons, function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', handler);
});
```

```html
<button>hey</button>
<button>hey233</button>
```